# Python Regex: Why my pattern does not match?

Tags: python, regex

Here is my pattern:

````
pattern_1a = re.compile(r"(?:```|\n)Item *1A\.?.{0,50}Risk Factors.*?(?:\n)Item *1B(?!u)", flags = re.I|re.S)
````

Why it does not match text like the following? What's wrong?

```
"""

Item 1A.

Risk
Factors

If we
are unable to commercialize
ADVEXIN
therapy in various markets for multiple indications,
particularly for the treatment of recurrent head and neck
cancer, our business will be harmed.

under which we may perform research and development services for
them in the future.

42

Table of Contents

We believe the foregoing transactions with insiders were and are
in our best interests and the best interests of our
stockholders. However, the transactions may cause conflicts of
interest with respect to those insiders.

Item 1B.

"""
```

Comment: You match `Risk Factors`, followed by any (optional) character, followed by a newline, followed by `Item *1B`. But `Item 1B` comes far after `Risk Factors`, not on the next line.

Comment: There is a star, not showing: Risk Factors*.?

Comment: Please try to format your question so that it's readable and understandable. Use code blocks and make sure that your actual code matches what the question displays.

Comment: Basically, I want to extract the section of Item 1A. I want to make sure that Item 1A. is followed by Risk Factors within next 50 characters.

Comment: The problem is your attempt to match `Item 1B` immediately after `Risk Factors`.

Comment: but Risk Factors is followed by .*?

Comment: Your new pattern does, your old pattern didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that will math with your actual text. Put `(` `)` around your string it will solve a lot of issue. See the solution below.

````
pattern_1a = re.compile(r"(?:```|\n)(Item 1A)[.\n]{0,50}(Risk Factors)([\n]|.)*(\nItem 1B.)(?!u)", flags = re.I|re.S)
````

Match evidence:
https://regexr.com/41ejq

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Risk Factors is spread over two lines. It is actually: Risk\nFactors

Using a general white space \s or a new line \n instead of a space matches the text.